# Get copy of password hash when changing password via ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, password-hash

I have a requirement to prevent users from re-using passwords they have already used in the past. To that end I want to record the hashed version of their password in a separate table so that I can compare any future password changes against the values in the table.

I currently use the following Identity method to change the password.

```
IdentityResult result = await this.AppUserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
```

This changes the password and stores it as a hash in the AspNetUsers table however is there a way I can return that hash so I can store it myself?

Comment: You can create a custom `UserStore` and override `SetPasswordHashAsync` to store the 'passwordhash' on some other table too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Section 3 of this article from Microsoft on how to do exactly what you are trying to do. I implemented this pattern and it works great.

[Implementing custom password policy using ASP.NET Identity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/01/06/implementing-custom-password-policy-using-asp-net-identity/)

Here is another article to get you going:

[How To Customize Password Policy in ASP.Net Identity](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/how-to-customize-password-policy-in-Asp-Net-identity/)